# Spring Data Jpa Concurrent User request performance hit

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I did a performance load test of my application with Jmeter and found that one of my rest get request is performing really bad on concurrent user request load of 100. I need some help to figure out if im doing something wrong. Let me give some insights into my application.

**Tech Stack**
My application is built upon Spring Boot, Rest, Spring Data JPA, Oracle, Kubernetes (2 pods), Hikari connection pool (maximumPoolSize: 100,maxLifetime: 30000,idleTimeout: 10000). For simple query(lookup) i 
use spring data jpa repository, the load test runs fine with similar latency, But for complex queries(search) i use custom repository with querydsl with autowired PersistenceContext and load test is really bad.

**Performance results :**

**Single Request**
One request takes around 5 seconds. its a complex join query and searches among 3 million records, filters 300k records and fetches top 20 records.

[image: Single Request Latency]
**Multiple Request**
If my understanding is correct, On 100 concurrent requests, the server spins up One thread per request, and all the request should return the response in 5 seconds. But all the threads get blocked in the repository layer, runs synchronously and the latency is increasing for the consecutive requests.
[image: Multiple Requests]
Any help would be much appreciated and let me know if further information is required.

**Sample Query:**
I have written a view that does all the joining and this is the sample query that i am running without any filters.

```
select * from variants_view order by variants_id asc fetch first 20 rows only.
```

Comment: Post your tables structure(better post your full generated sql with everything) so people can get proper view on this behaviour

Comment: Your pool looks quite big. You should read the HikariCP article about pool sizing.

Comment: Pawel , Its running an a view, I have added the query that im using. 

Kayaman, Yes I will have a look into it. Earlier i had 25, But i have increased the pool size because some requests are getting timed out because the other requests didnt release the connection yet. But yes i will check and see if that could be a problem.

Comment: if you have grafana installed, then you can check for the memory limit that Pod has and the limit it is taking at the runtime, also check for cpu